# IBM Cognos 10 - Smple way to globally rename a table column?

Tags: sdk, rename, cognos

My client has decided they want to rename a very commonly used data item name.
So, for example, the database has a column called 'Cost' and they see 'Cost' on a heap of reports.
The client now wants to see 'Net Cost' everywhere.
So we need to change every occurrence of 'Cost' and change it to 'Net Cost'

I can do this in Framework Manager easily enough, and I can even run Tools > Report Dependency to find all the reports that use the 'Cost' column. But if there's 4,000 of them, that's a lot of work to update them all.

One idea is to deploy the entire content store to a Cognos Deployment zip file, extract that & do a global search & replace on the XML. But that's going to be messy & dangerous.

Option 2 is to use MotioPI to do a search & replace. I don't think the client will spring for buying this product just for this task.

Are there other options?

- has anyone written anything in the Cognos SDK which will do a rename?
- has someone investigated the Content Store database to the degree
  that they could do a rename on all the report specs in SQL?
- are there other options I've overlooked?

Any ideas would be greatly welcomed ...

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is the way to go. This essentially boils down to an XML find-and-replace scenario. You'll need to isolate just the instances of the word "Cost" which are relevant to you. This may involve the start and end tags.

To change the data source reference across reports, you'll need to find and replace on the three part name `[Presentation Layer].[Namespace].[Cost]`. If there are filters on the item, they may just reference the one part name from the Query. Likewise, any derived queries would reference the two part name. Handle these by looking through the XML report spec and figuring out how to isolate the text.

I'm assuming your column names are set to inherit the business name from the model and not hard coded (`Source Type` should be `Data Item Label`, NOT `Text`). If not, you'll need to handle these as well. Looking at the XML, you would see `<staticValue>Cost</staticValue>` for these.

It's not really dangerous as you have a backup. Just take multiple passes, each with as granular a find and replace as possible.

Motio will just look at the values inside the tags, so you will be unable to isolate `Cost`, thus it can't be used for this. However, it would come in handy for mass validation of reports after the find and replace. A one seat license for the year could be justified by the amount of development time it could save here.

Comment: There's one really really big if here.  If you use folders inside your FM model, those folders don't show up in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DRU? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021248)
I have used this tool before to do what you are describing.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least search for text in the Content Store (v10.2.1) using something like:

```
set define off
select distinct T4.name as folder_name, T2.name as report_name
from cmobjprops7 T1
inner join cmobjnames T2 on T1.cmid=T2.cmid
inner join cmobjects T3 on T1.cmid=T3.cmid
inner join cmobjnames T4 on T3.pcmid=T4.cmid
inner join (   -- only want the latest version (this still shows reports that have been deleted)
     Select T4.name as folder_name, T2.name as report_name, max(T3.modified) as latest_version_date
     from cmobjnames T2 
          inner join cmobjects T3 on T2.cmid=T3.cmid
          inner join cmobjnames T4 on T3.pcmid=T4.cmid
     Where T2.Name like ‘%myReport%’ -- search only reports with 'myReport' i the name
        and substr(T4.name,1,1) in ('Project Zeus','Project Jupiter')   -- search only folders with this in the name
     Group by T4.name, T2.name
     ) TL on TL.folder_name=T4.name and TL.report_name=T2.name and TL.latest_version_date=T3.modified
where T1.spec like '%[namespace].[column_name]%'        -- text you want to find
and substr(T4.name,1,2) in ('Project Zeus','Project Jupiter')
    order by 1 desc, 2;
```